# Magnifying glass shows UIWindow behind

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uilongpressgesturerecogni

We have an app with a burger menu navigation, the menu itself is a window that lies behind the keywindow.

When the user long presses a uitextfield and brings up the magnifying glass, the magnifying glass shows the content of the UIWindow behind.

Has anyone got any ideas

[Video](https://youtu.be/CvlLaFp3vwE)

[image: View hierarchy]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A workaround for this is setting windowLevel to -1 like

```
self.navigationWindow.windowLevel = -1;
```

where navigationWindow is the window containing the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problems.
My solution is:
    UIWindow* oldWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    delegate.newWindow.hidden = NO;
    [delegate.newWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
    oldWindow.hidden = YES;

it works.
But there will be a black twinkle during the transition.

Comment: I dont want to hide the window. The the magnifying glass should reflect what is currently in front.

Comment: Then try windowLevel, it may helps: frontWindow.windowlevel = behindeWindow.windowLevel + 0.1;

Answer (score 0):

Set `window?.makeKeyAndVisible()` After `window?.rootViewController = whatever`

Issue happens with me when I do the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Actually your application UIWindow::windowLevel property (window z-index) is 0 by default. Your login UIWindow::windowLevel is also 0 by default.

Adjust your login window level

```
loginWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert
```