# iOS 11 magnifier does not show text when text field is in scrollview?

Tags: uitextfield, uisearchbar, ios11, editing

When long-pressing text in a uitextfield and uisearchbar the magnifier pops up that allows you to see the content of those fields more clearly, and edit them. However, I have uitextfield and uisearchbar in a scroll view, and then the magnifier is unable to show anything in that scroll view, including text entered. As far as I know I have no control over the magnifier. Any ideas?

Comment: In the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36692542/magnifying-glass-shows-uiwindow-behind the windowlevel is a factor. If I do self.view.window.windowLevel += 0.1; indeed the magnifying glass shows ok. Would it be an iOS 11 bug that the window level is not correct?

Answer (score 0):

I have sort of "solved" this problem by adding:

For UISearchBar:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {    
    self.view.window.windowLevel += 0.0001;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    self.view.window.windowLevel += 0.0001;
}
```

For UITextField:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {    
    self.view.window.windowLevel += 0.0001;
}
```

I have tried to add `self.view.window.windowLevel += 0.0001;` to viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear, too, but to no avail. I'm happy above works, but I'd like to ***understand*** it better too.